# Internet/Router Problems

Tags: router, internet

Hi guys so the problem i am having which i see many people have had is that i cant go on anything online such as steam,league of legends,elder scrolls online etc. Now what i have found out it is not my computer because i can go on these things on a friends internet. For some reason i can surf the internet such as google,youtube,twitter,facebook and so on but i cant login into online games or game platforms and this has been like this for the past week. Please Help!!

Comment: what i have tried to fix this problem is ipconfig /flushdns,factory resetting my router,restarting my pc and the router and more

Comment: i have had this problem twice in the past but those only lasted for a day but this problem has been occurring for almost a week and seems like its not going to go away

Comment: Have you power cycled your router and modem or if it just a router/modem combination power cycle that?

Comment: its a router/modem combination

Comment: i will try that and report back in a minute

Comment: it didnt help the issue

Comment: its still being an ahole

Comment: Is it giving you any kinds or errors? Can you and has anyone changed any of the settings on the router? Need some more helpful details. Or some kind of errors so we can help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: this problem happened last friday and no one in my family is smart enough with computers to go into the router

Comment: i got home from school and when i went onto my pc to play some games with friends it wouldnt let me connect to league or steam

Comment: Check the IP address is assigned to the router's WAN port. Is it a private address? If so, your ISP is using CGN.

Comment: no it isnt a private address and i never had to do anything with my router or pc for me to play online games

Answer (score 1):

Things that usually work for me:

1. Check your firewall - Resetting to default clears some problems.
2. Check the ports on your modem/router. You need some open for specific games
3. Check and make sure your IPV4 is set to automatic for IP & DNS.
4. Update modem/router firmware
5. Hold modem router reset button for about 30 seconds to reset

Will

Comment: the thing is i never had to open my ports previously to play the games that i have

Comment: i have reset my router twice,i have reset my firewall to default it didnt do nothing,my router doesnt need an update

Comment: its something got to do with my router or internet because i went to my cousins on Saturday and could go on the things that i cant go on my internet

Comment: @Viperskull16 do you have another computer or laptop you can get on to check if its your Computer?